# Order of integration for sign-function

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, multivariable-calculus, fourier-analysis

> Evaluate $\int_{0}^{1}\left ( \int_{0}^{1}f\left ( x,y \right )dx \right )dy$ and $\int_{0}^{1}\left ( \int_{0}^{1}f\left ( x,y \right )dy \right )dx$

Given that
 $f\left ( x,y \right )= \frac{{sgn}\left ( y-x \right )}{{{max}}\left ( y-x \right )^{2}}$ and is defined on the interval $ \left ( x,y \right )\in \left [ 0,1 \right ] \times \left [ 0,1 \right ]$

---

Attempt: We need to first justify the order of integration by ensuring that the function is uniformly convergent. But it is not, and thus we cannot invoke Dominated Convergence Theorem. Any alternative methods?

Comment: $\max(y-x)$ is a typo.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you meant
$$
f(x,y)=\frac{\text{sgn}(y-x)}{\max(x,y)^{2}}.
$$
For fixed $y$,
$$
\int_{0}^{1}f(x,y)dx=\int_{0}^{y}\frac{1}{y^{2}}dx-\int_{y}^{1}\frac{1}{x^{2}}dx=\frac{1}{y}+\left(1-\frac{1}{y}\right)=1.
$$
Therefore,
$$
\int_{0}^{1}\left(\int_{0}^{1}f(x,y)dx\right)dy=\int_{0}^{1}dy=1.
$$
Similarly, for fixed $x$,
$$
\int_{0}^{1}f(x,y)dy=-\int_{0}^{x}\frac{1}{x^{2}}dy+\int_{x}^{1}\frac{1}{y^{2}}dy=-\frac{1}{x}-\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)=-1.
$$
Therefore,
$$
\int_{0}^{1}\left(\int_{0}^{1}f(x,y)dy\right)dx=\int_{0}^{1}-dx=-1.
$$
Note that the order of integration matters here. If you are familiar with it, you can check that the conditions of the Fubini-Tonelli theorem are not satisfied.

Comment: Thanks. I haven't heard of Fubini-Tonelli. I checked quickly: is it correct that the it breaks down to function not measurable?

Comment: Fubini-Tonelli requires the function to be measurable **and integrable** on the product space (i.e., $\int_{X \times Y} |f(x,y)| d(x,y) < \infty$). The key thing here is that this is a statement about integrability **with respect to the product space**.